# Ajax http request close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using **Ajax** to display an html page when a button is clicked.

What I need is to create another button to close the ajax html page. I have tried the abort() but that's not what I need, I need to close the page not to abort the HTTP Request.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <p id="demo">When you click the button it will load an HTML page</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Open HTML Page</button>

  <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "mypage.html", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `xhttp.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" 
  onclick="document.querySelector('#demo').style.display='none'">Close HTML Page</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" 
  onclick="document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML==''">Close HTML Page</button>
```

Either can be attached unobtrusively using an ID on the button

If you use the first, you need to add to loading:

```
document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;      
document.querySelector('#demo').style.display="";
```

Comment: Your code is perfect, but why when I close it and open it again a word shows "undefined"?   @mplungjan

Comment: Do you always open the same page? Then don't do the ajax the second time, just show the page again